# Kerberos events are not logged on Windows 7

Tags: logging, kerberos

I tried to configure Windows 7 machine with our web-server running on it to log Kerberos-related events (meaning Windows system Log). I followed these instructions: [How to enable Kerberos event logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262177).
In order to test this setting, I changed time on a demo client machine so that 'Clock skew too great' error would be raised. The exception itself was raised on a server, however, no logs were found in System Log. Even though I expect them to be logged only on a server machine, I also checked logs the same way on client machine, and even on a domain machine (which was rather a wild guess). As expected, no error events were found in system log.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this too, but it didn't work for me either, probably because Windows 7 is not listed in the "Applies to" section the link.